# Sublime Text: Improved LaTeX spell check

Tags: latex, sublimetext, spell-checking

The in-built spell check of Sublime Text has problems with the `{}` brackets in LaTeX. To give you an example:

In `\textbf{typology for systemic problems}` `typology` is shown as an error. Right mouse click offers me to correct it to `typology` which results in `\typology for systemic problems}`.

Can I somehow improve ST's capabilities for detecting the `{}` correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't use any LaTeX syntax highlighting. Set Syntax to LaTeX will solve this.

[image]